# How to fail Gitlab pipeline if there are failed test in JUnit report

Tags: junit, gitlab, maven-surefire-plugin

My project (mobile application) has Gitlab pipeline with stage for running UI tests (Appium) based on TestNG and maven. with surefire plugin.
I set up displaying JUnit reports in pipeline results as artifacts
artifacts:reports:junit: - surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
and it is correctly displayed on pipeline page.
But even if there are failed tests in report, job is still marked as succeeded, and pipeline is green.
Is it possible to fail pipeline if report contains failed tests?

Comment: That's weird, because the [docs say](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/junit_test_reports.html#overview) that if the test fails, the pipeline should too. If you can easily reproduce this and you're on a newer version, I suggest filing a bug report https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues

Answer (score 3):

It seems Gitlab will only fail the pipeline if the test process exits with a non zero code, and it won't parse the JUnit xml files to determine the success of a pipeline (https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-fail-job-and-pipeline-if-there-are-failed-tests-in-junit-report/37039/3)

Here is what I did to address this issue:

1. Run your test and collect the results in a file

```
# the echo command will only be run when the test process exits with a non zero code,
# and the entire step will still return 0 as the exit code
run_your_test_for_example_mvn_verify || echo "there is Maven test failure" >> failures.log 
run_your_test_for_example_poetry_pytest || echo "there is pytest failure" >> failures.log
```

2. Test the presence of this result file later

```
# if the failures.log file exists, 
# the command below will return false and will fail the pipeline
test ! -f failures.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Had this exact same problem just now!

It seems GitLab doesn’t fail a pipeline with test failures. Seems like a weird choice by GitLab but it is what it is.

I solved it like this (`.gitlab-ci` file is condensed to just the important parts):

```yaml
lint-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    # Your build steps that create the JUnit XML
    - ./do_build.sh
    # Horrible way of parsing XML
    - test -f lint.xml && grep -L "<failure" lint.xml
```

There doesn't seem to be any "blessed" tools to use for parsing JUnit XML files. Using `test` and `grep` together is definitely a hack, but it hopefully won't break.

[GitLab forum reference confirming that failures/errors/warnings in test XML files do not fail the pipeline](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-fail-job-and-pipeline-if-there-are-failed-tests-in-junit-report).

Answer (score 0):

In my view parsing the test report for a certain regex may not be the optimal solution. Here is how I solved it -> I'm using TestNG lib to run my selenium UI test. TestNG generates multiple test result xml files, like testng-passed.xml, testng-failed.xml, testng-skipped.xml etc.
The failed xml is created only if there is any test failure, now we can use this condition (presence of testng-failed.xml) to either pass or fail the pipeline.

------------ **gitlab-ci.yml code snippet:** ----------

```
  variables:
    TESTNG_FAILED_XML: jar/test-output/testng-failed.xml

  script:
    - #Your test-run command
    - |
      if [[ -f "$TESTNG_FAILED_XML" ]]; then
        echo "Test failures observed as TestNG-Failed file exists."
        exit 1
      else
        echo "All tests passed Successfully."
      fi
```

---

Note: The above should be within your script section, it will NOT work within after_script section.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure maven/surefire to fail the build when the tests fail, then Gitlab should pick up on the fact that the build failed and thus fail the job and pipeline.