# Gitlab Pipeline is not aborting on Junit test case failure

Tags: unit-testing, junit, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

Gitlab Version: v14.1.1
Gitlab pipeline is succeeding even though there is a failed test cases in unit test.

**Gitlab.yaml code:**

```
unit-test:
  stage: Test
  script:
    - npm run test
  needs:
    - lint
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - coverage
    reports:
      junit:
        - junit.xml
      cobertura:
        - coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml
    expire_in: 4 days
  only:
    - test-case-testing
    - merge_requests
```

**Test Results:**

[image]

**Update: test command used in package.json**

```
"test": "node ./node_modules/nyc/bin/nyc.js --reporter=cobertura --reporter=html node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber-js src/use-cases --parallel 5 --format=json --fail-fast --require \"src/use-cases/**/!(index).js\" | cucumber-junit > junit.xml",
```

How can I abort the Gitlab pipeline when there are any failed test cases? I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61524738/how-to-fail-gitlab-pipeline-if-there-are-failed-test-in-junit-report) but couldn't figure out what exact changes should I do?

Comment: Can you please include the package script block where you define the `test` command? It's likely that the exit code of your script block is always returning 0 (which would make the gitlab job pass, even with failing tests). GitLab doesn't care about the failures in the JUnit report, it only passes or fails the job based on the exit code of the test command.

Comment: Hello @Patrick, Thank you for your reply! Let me add the test script block.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly your issue. The last command on your chain `cucumber-junit > junit.xml` is returning 0, so regardless of the status of the node test run you'll be getting an exit code 0 from the `test` command. You could likely grep the junit command for the word `failure` and fail the job if you find it, but the best option would be to move the cucumber command elsewhere so the node command fails appropriately.

Comment: Hello Patrick, You're right. I had managed this failure with following command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following change in script managed the failure.

```
  stage: Test
  script:
    - npm run test
    - test -f junit.xml && grep -L "<failure" junit.xml
```

and this resolved the issue.